# Entity Framework code first, one to one relationship - different behaviour

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

I have 2 objects, which binding to 3-d with one to one relationship:

```
public class Project : AuditInfoComplete
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Ecwid Ecwid { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ProjectDomain ProjectDomain { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class Ecwid
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Project")]
    [DataMember]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string EcwidShopID { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public class ProjectDomain
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Project")]
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

In DbContext I have this:

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Ecwid>().HasKey(p => p.ProjectId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOptional(p => p.Ecwid).WithRequired(p => p.Project).WillCascadeOnDelete();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectDomain>().HasKey(p => p.ProjectId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Project>().HasOptional(p => p.ProjectDomain).WithRequired(p => p.Project).WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

When I'm creating Project - "Ecwid" object created automatically for me in database, but "Project Domain" object is not creating. Why behaviour is different?

Comment: That's your model. Where is the code that exercises it? Are you `var p = Project(); p.ProjectDomain = new ProjectDomain();` ?

Comment: No just Project p = new Project(); Then ProjectsRepository.Add(p). Commit it, and in database project exists, ecwid exists and ProjectDomain not exists

Comment: If I will add, like you said, p.ProjectDomain =new ProjectDomain() - it will create row in database correct.